# Undemocratic systems that shift from democratic systems without violence

Tags: political-system, history

Thinking about the rising power of multinational corporations over national governments, I've been debating with a friend on how the seemingly more and more obsolete democratic systems like in the US or most EU nations could be progressively shifting to a system that could reestablish the power of a small group of unelected people over the population, without any radical change from the current system.

Our discussion deadlocked as we found no example, in our knowledge of history, where any kind of political system formed out of democracy without any violence.

So the question is, has something like that ever happened?

Comment: "obsolete" because seemingly not able to handle the power of megacorperations.

Comment: “Western democracy” itself is quite new and evolving so it's not like there is a whole lot of past experience to look back to.

Comment: This is a matter of opinion, but personally I am also very worried about the increasing power that multinational corporations gets and the lowering power of the governments. The problem is that we need some proof that this is a threat to democracy.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a better fit on history and isn't on topic here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That depends on your definition of democracy, not to mention of "no violence". As to the latter, to take an extreme case, if a new type of government comes to power, and in the course of it two drunks in a bar have an argument about whether the new government is better than the old and they throw a couple of punches, and that is the only violence, would you say that that means it failed the "no violence" test? I'd say absolute zero violence is probably almost impossible.

That said: Rome turned from a republic to a dictatorship with relatively little violence. Yes, there were a series of civil wars, but those wars took place under the republic. It's a common analysis to say that the people accepted the dictatorship because they believed a strong enough government could end the civil wars.

Western Europe and he US are drifting from democracies to rule by an unelected elite with very little violence.

Ancient Israel went from a rather libertarian society to a monarchy with no apparent violence. In that case the people generally favored it because they believed a king could better maintain a standing army to protect them from foreign invasion.

** Further thought **

The Roman Empire was probably a bad example. There was fighting by the Republicans under Brutus against the Imperialists under Augustus. Duh, forgetting my Shakespeare, even.

But a much better example hit me, an absolute classic example: Nazi Germany. Hitler came to power through free elections and political maneuvering. Then of course once in power he took steps to make it impossible for him to be voted out of power.

The Nazis did try to overthrow the government by force -- the "Beer Hall Putsch" -- but this failed. They then switched to using legal means.

Comment: Hitler did two coups. In the end, his SA murdered various political oponents. Would not call this non-violental.

Comment: "Western Europe and he US are drifting from democracies to rule by an unelected elite with very little violence." I haven't heard any suggestions of implementing an "unelected" elite. Generally they're elected from a very limited pool of candidates. Care to explain?

Comment: Can you provide sources for the claims about Israel, Rome and Europe/US?

Comment: @mart Hmm, I'd think those would all fall under "common knowledge". For Rome, how about Seutonius's "The Twelve Caesars" and Plutarch's "Lives of the Noble Greeks and Romans". For Israel, the books of Judges and 1 Samuel in the Bible. For the U.S., your daily newspaper.

Comment: @PointlessSpike By "unelected elites" I was thinking of the Supreme Court, professional bureaucrats, and leadership of the two major political parties.

Comment: @Sempie I'm not sure what you mean by "two coups". The Nazis did not come to power through a violent coup: they came to power by winning an election and then maneuvering to dominate the government. Yes, once in power they had lots of people they didn't like killed, but to the best of my knowledge, they didn't kill anyone to get power. Or if there are cases I am forgetting or don't know about, still, they didn't have a violent revolution like the French or Russian revolutions, so it was RELATIVELY non-violent. See the first paragraph of my post.

Comment: @Jay The US's supreme court and bureaucrats aren't politicians. Only politicians are elected. This is the norm in every system I'm aware of. The leadership of the two major political parties *are* elected. You can vote for someone else. The same goes for Europe.

Comment: @PointlessSpike I didn't say "unelected politicians": I said "unelected elite". To say, "all the people you are allowed to vote for are subject to popular vote" is a tautology, but doesn't answer the question, "who is really in charge?" In imperial Rome, the senators, consuls, tribunes, etc were all elected. But they had little real power: It was the emperor, who was not elected, who was in charge. In the U.S., the Supreme Court has the power to overturn any law or presidential order they don't like. They are the ultimate authority, and they are not elected.

Comment: @PointlessSpike Not sure what you mean when you say that leadership of the two major parties are elected. They are not elected by a vote of the people. I have never seen "Democratic national committee chairman" on any ballot.

Comment: @Jay, fair enough, you have a point. We all seem to dance around shouting "we're democratic" while diluting the democracy to the point where we should really be muttering "well, kind of" under our breath.

Comment: @PointlessSpike Exactly. I'm not saying the U.S. is a fascist dictatorship. Obviously not. But I think it is fair to say that we are moving in the direction of less individual freedom and more power in the hands of unelected people. And, to get back to the original question, this has happened without violence. It's not like the army was divided between those supporting Congress and those supporting the courts, and the court faction won a pitched battle. Rather, over the years the courts have assumed more power for themselves, and for whatever reason, Congress has meekly accepted this. Etc.

Comment: What do you define as "undemocratic"? No country has true, direct democracy as far as I'm aware of.

Comment: In the run up to the election there were constant street battles between nazis and communists - but because the communists were also seen as enemies of the state that certainly wasn't a coup.

Comment: @PointlessSpike Switzerland has a direct democracy. However, in my opinion it is very biased toward large private companies as those have the resources to manipulate the population easily, and to always get votes in their favour. There is no laws against this in Switzerland (this is just my opinion, many other swiss people will disagree)

Comment: This is probably nitpicking, but it's only mostly a direct democracy. There are still representatives that make some of the decisions. It's the closest thing around, but still not quite there. You could call it "undemocratic" that the Federal Council isn't directly elected by the people, that was my point.

Comment: @PointlessSpike Absolutely, but currently the federal council is not the bottleneck of Switzerland's democracy. The parlement can veto any decision made by it, and the people themselves can veto any decision made by the parliment. The bottleneck of democracy is, in my opinion, the lobbies, as well as international relationships.

Answer (score 1):

Since this question is a bit broad, it's hard to answer precisely. However, there is a couple of examples in my mind where more or less democratic systems evolved into either very flawed democracies or dictatorships, without any military intervention or any extremist groups overtaking the government.

- Near the end of the USSR in the late 80s, Gorbachev launched his *Gastnost* program and started to allow opposition parties and freedom of speech. This included all the former soviet republics. It can be argued that even after the reforms USSR wasn't fully democratic. However, the majority of ex-USSR central asian republics now forbid freedom of speech and oposition parties again. Turkmenistan is more or less North Korea 2.0.
- A couple Central Europe countries gained a democratic elected government after World War I, but shifted undemocratic again with little violence after half a dozen of years: Hungary, Poland, Romania, Bulgaria, Yougoslavia. Although violence was definitely present, it was not comparable to the repeated acts violence happened before during the overthrow of government in Italy, Germany and Austria.
- Many countries impose a "Martial law" when a more powerful neighbour is at war. This gives temporary more power to the government, because decisions has to be taken very quickly and the a democratic debate would be a huge waste of time, in addition to reveal the government intention to their potential enemies immediately as the decision is taking. Switzerland and Sweden during World War II are good examples of this.

As for countries being taken over by a couple of multinational companies, I can't really answer. Some of the poorer countries in Africa and Asia are probably *de facto* in such a situation, however, they didn't have a democratic past.

Answer (score -1):

If an undemocratic system arose from democracy, then they have no reason to remove democratic institutions as a facade, after all, all these institutions led them to power.

Explicitely removing democracy may be needed if one wants to proclaim a monarchy. Consider

- Naponelon III's proclamation as emperor of France after he was elected president.
- Yuan Shikai's proclamation as emperor of China after he was elected president.

Although in the later case it sparked a civil war post-factum.